# JQuery UI uses which version of JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am using JQuery UI and the example includes these header tags:

```
<!--JQuery UI-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Does The first script tag use "jquery-1.12.4.js", but isn't the newest version of jQuery 2.2.4 or 3.0? Why doesn't JQuery UI use that? I already have alot of code running with V2.2.4 (that I included earlier) but when I include the second script I get conflicts and I dont want to use .noConflict and go back and replace all the "$" signs I used.

Does JQuery UI use an older version?

Comment: I assume it depends on which version of jQuery UI you're using.  I'd also assume that jQuery UI would depend on the version of jQuery available at release time, or older.

Comment: [**This**](https://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-ui-1-11-4-compatible-with-jquery-2-1-4) may be useful

Comment: "jQuery UI 1.12 supports jQuery 1.7 and newer." https://api.jqueryui.com/

Comment: *"when I include the second script I get conflicts"* - what script? how/where did you include it? Please be specific.

Answer (score 2):

jQueryUI supports jQuery version 1.7 and up. This includes jQuery 2.* and jQuery 3.* their examples are just a bit dated in that they have not updated the references to the new versions of jQuery.

You can just use your current references to the version of jQuery you are using.

The errors you are getting are because you are referencing jQuery twice.